# Inconsistency in PHP documentation?

Tags: php, mysql, list, pdo, specifications

I am currently reading through the PHP specification here: https://github.com/php/php-langspec

1. Now, I saw the *list-intrinsic* specification [here](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#list), which states that for a *list-intrinsic* construct like below, the right-hand side of the *simple-assignment-expression* **must be an expression that designates an array**:

   > list  *(  list-expression-list<sub>opt</sub>  )* = *expression*
2. But the documentation of *list* from php.net [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), gives an example containing this:

   ```
   $result = $pdo->query("SELECT id, name, salary FROM employees");
   while (list($id, $name, $salary) = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
       //output $id, $name and $salary
   }
   ```

The thing is that `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` returns `FALSE` if there is no further row. But the right-hand side of the *assignment-expression*  must be an array - and `FALSE` is not an array. So this would result in a fatal-error, right?

Have I missed something in the specification, or is this really an inconsistency?

---

[According PHP bugreport](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68993)

Comment: I believe that the syntax you're noting uses a higher priority for the assignment `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` that is picked up by the logic of the `while` loop, which recognises its termination condition before execution of the `list()`, so it doesn't result in a fatal error

Comment: I suppose the best explanation is that you should think of `list(..)=` as being an operator, not of `list(..)` being an operand that works with the `=` operator.

Comment: @MarkBaker Interesting idea. If you could find a source for this somewhere in the specifications, this would be the perfect answer.

Comment: @MarkBaker Testing this for myself, the expression `list(...) = something` will seemingly never give an error or warning, even if used outside a while loop. Not for a boolean, not for an int, not for an array with an other width than the arguments of list.

Comment: I can't provide such, and you may indeed have found a discrepancy in the specification.... in which case the best place to ask is the specification github repo itself, rather than StackOverflow

Comment: @deceze The specification of the [_simple-assignment-expression_](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#simple-assignment) states that the returned value of the assignment is the `type and value of the left-hand operand after the store has taken place`. The value of the left-hand-operand is the value of the _list-intrinsic_. So if the right-hand-operand is not an array, the _list-intrinsic_'s constraints would have been violated and a fatal error would have been produced, right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My guess would be short circuit boolean evaluation of `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` resulting in a false, automatically triggering the end of `while` condition without needing to evaluate the assignment to the `list()` expression

Comment: @MarkBaker I understand. But this behavior would also end in an inconsistency. Because the value of a [_simple-assignment-expression_](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#simple-assignment) is specified to depend on the value of the left-hand-operand after the store, it would be illegal, not to evaluate the left-hand-operand, __except__ if no difference would be detectable. But with the _list-intrinsic_, the different behavior __would be detectable__, because no error would be created where it should be. So that is inconsistent too.

Comment: Then take it up with the core developers who've been working on that language spec directly.... asking on Stack Overflow isn't going to get clarification, only supposition and surmise on how the spec might be interpreted

Comment: @MarkBaker Alright. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: php.net version specific documentation is long overdue. Until people responsible for it decide to implement such a feature it would be wise to simply invest in a crystal ball. Yeah I know, not much of a help. Wasn't for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#list) says the following, where "list-intrinsic" is a grammar that contains all valid forms `list(...)` may have.

> list-intrinsic must be used as the left-hand operand in a simple-assignment-expression of which the right-hand operand must be an expression that designates an array (called the source array).

What designates an array? [The documentation](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/12-arrays.md) says this:

> An array is a data structure that contains a collection of zero or more elements. The elements of an array need not have the same type, and the type of an array element can change over its lifetime.

I think you are correct in thinking that `FALSE`, a boolean, does not qualify as *anything designating an array* as it is not a collection.

What does 'must' mean in this context? If we read the [Conformance](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/02-conformance.md#conformance) part of the documentation we find:

> In this specification, "must" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "must not" is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
>
> If a "must" or "must not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this specification by the words "undefined behavior" or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe "behavior that is undefined".

Are you correct in assuming that an fatal error must be raised? I think you are not correct in assuming so. Unless noted under "semantics" that a fatal error will occur, lack of a specification of behaviour, or a 'must' under constraints means that behaviour of that part of the language is not defined. It can work. It can throw an error, a fatal error. It can create an AI that will destroy all of us, turn the moon purple, or blow up the server. It is undefined.

---

So what is happening? The documentation says under semantics the following:

> This intrinsic assigns zero or more elements of the source array to the target variables. On success, it returns a copy of the source array. If the source array is actually the value NULL, this is consider a failure, and the return value from list is undefined.
>
> All elements in the source array having keys of type string are ignored. The element having an int key of 0 is assigned to the first target variable, the element having an int key of 1 is assigned to the second target variable, and so on, until all target variables have been assigned. Any other array elements are ignored. If there are fewer source array elements having int keys than there are target variables, the unassigned target variables are set to NULL and a non-fatal error is produced.

Testing gives the following results:

```
$a = 1;
$z = FALSE;
$e = (list( $a, $b ) = $z);

var_dump($a); //NULL
var_dump($b); //NULL
var_dump($z); //FALSE

var_dump($e); //FALSE
```

In fact, `$z = $e` for any `$z` it seems, even if `$z = NULL`. No notice, warning or error is generated for any value I have tested, unless the length of the source array is less than the amount of variables in the list-intrensic expression. In this case a `Notice: Undefined offset` is shown.

It seems that any non-iterateble expression is treated as if it is a NULL value (but this is undefined behaviour); in my version of PHP it seems that any NULL value cuts off assignment halfway; it will not be iterated, but the preliminary part of assigning NULL to all variables is executed.

The expression `while (list($id, $name, $salary) = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))` will thus assign `NULL` to `$id`, `$name` and `$salary`, and the `FALSE` value will terminate the while-loop. This behaviour is not expected or guaranteed by the language specification however.

Answer (score 5):

This is deliberately done in the implementation of php to allow this dubious piece of code:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
  // ...
}
```

The result of `each()` may be `false` and would otherwise have triggered a nasty error, so while this behaviour is seemingly in violation with the specification it's mostly done to maintain backwards compatibility.

It's possible, though unlikely, that the next version of PHP will abolish this behaviour but at this point I would suggest that the specification could be edited to reflect this particular artefact, though the implied undefined behaviour could serve that purpose as well :)

#### Geeky details

The code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bff4c47fa7f2b356bddd0a87f07ed32d61ec56fe/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L1641); currently, the right-hand side expression supports:

1. An array,
2. An object that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/arrayaccess),
3. Something else.

In the case of "something else" it will just assign `null` to all the list variables.

#### Update

[Nikita Popov](https://github.com/nikic) has proposed the following specification update as part of a [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/pull/111/files):

> list-intrinsic must be used as the left-hand operand in a simple-assignment-expression of which the right-hand operand must be an expression that designates an array **or object implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface** (called the source array).

...

> This intrinsic assigns one or more elements of the source array to the target variables. On success, it returns a copy of the source array. If the source array is not an array **or object implementing `ArrayAccess` no assignments are performed and the return value is NULL.**

*(Changes emphasised)*

Comment: This is actually just another example for such an inconsistency: The thing is that these examples (including [those on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php)) seem to work. But the specification on github specifies such code as invalid. The question is whether I missed something __in the github specification__, or whether this is really an inconsistency.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Perhaps it could be better phrased in the sense that "no, you didn't miss something, this is php being backwards compatible" :)

Comment: If that is true, the backwards-compatibility for this is inconsistent with the specification. At some points, the specification has such _"backwards-compatibility features"_, but not for the _list-intrinsic_. Let's just see what the core-developers will answer to the bug-report ;)

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Yeah, it probably should be documented in the specification :)

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock the specification was written in 2014 (and I don't think it is final yet) while the code of the interpreter allows this PHP construction since the dawn of the PHP (the mid of the 90s). I personally never used `each()` and I think it is just a remnant of the older versions of PHP (3.0 and less) (and it can be dropped without many people noticing) but the current interpreter attempts to be backward compatible with them (as much as possible). The specification, on the other hand, attempts to standardize the current behaviour and the **future** versions of PHP.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock I've added a comment to the bug report based on a recent proposal made by another core dev, hope it helps :)